# Programmatically adjust cell color

Tags: jquery

I have a table with numeric values in some (not all) cells

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The lowest value is 0, and I have no way of knowing what the max value could be, but it's probably in low double-digits.

I would like to use jQuery to change the background of each cell with red shift towards the higher numbers. So it, the value in a cell is zero, the color is #FFFFCC and the highest is #CC0000.

So I think this could be accomplished with the following steps:

1. Find the lowest and the highest values
2. Calculate color increment
3. Assign background colors

Before I jump into re-invention of a wheel, I wanted to check if something like this has been done and if yes, if someone would point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [**HeatColor**](http://www.jnathanson.com/blog/client/jquery/heatcolor/), a jQuery plugin that does exactly this.

Comment: I love it when people share their jquery plugins with the world